# Get location for Kivy Garden MapView

Tags: python, kivy

I need get current location in GPS and pass for mapview.
My code not working, return error:
Code working, if in kv langue in MapView add lat: and lon: numeric value.
Any ideas for get values lat and lon from function on_locations ?

```
ValueError: None is not allowed for MapView.lat
```

Code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import gps
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import json
import kivy.garden.mapview

kv = '''
#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import sys sys
#:import MapSource mapview.MapSource

BoxLayout:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: C('#ffffff')
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MapView:
            lat: app.on_location(self.lat)
            lon: app.on_location(self.long)
            zoom: 13
            map_source: MapSource(sys.argv[1], attribution="") if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "osm"
            MapMarkerPopup:
                lat: app.on_location(self.lat)
                lon: app.on_location(self.long)
                popup_size: dp(230), dp(130)
                Bubble:
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: "horizontal"
                        padding: "5dp"
                        Label:
                            text: "[b]Você está aqui![/b]"
                            markup: True
                            halign: "center"
    BoxLayout:
        assunto: assunto
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [30, 30, 30, 100]
        spacing: 10
        Spinner:
            id: assunto
            text: 'Selecionar Assunto'
            background_color: C('#1180c4')
            background_normal: ''
            values: ('Buraco e Pavimentação', 'Calçadas guias e Postes', 'Ciclovias, Faixas e outros', 'Semáforos, sinalização e outros.', 'Iluminação Pública')
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '40dp'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            height: '40dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            ToggleButton:
                text: 'Ler Localizacao' if self.state == 'normal' else 'Parar Leitura'
                on_state:
                    app.start(1000, 0) if self.state == 'down' else \
                    app.stop()
            Button:
                text: 'Salvar'
                on_press: app.salvarLocalizacao()
'''

class GpsTest(App):
    gps_get = StringProperty()
    gps_location = StringProperty()
    gps_status = StringProperty()
    detail_text = StringProperty()


    def build(self):
        try:
            gps.configure(on_location=self.on_location,
                          on_status=self.on_status)

        except NotImplementedError:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
            self.gps_status = 'Por favor, ative o GPS'
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def start(self, minTime, minDistance):
        gps.start(minTime, minDistance)

    def stop(self):
        gps.stop()

    @mainthread
    def on_location(self, **kwargs):
        self.lat = kwargs.get('lat')
        self.long = kwargs.get('lon')


    @mainthread
    def on_status(self, stype, status):
        self.gps_status = 'type={}\n{}'.format(stype, status)

    def on_pause(self):
        gps.stop()
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        gps.start(1000, 0)
        pass

    def salvarLocalizacao(self):

        if self.root.ids.assunto.text == "Buraco e Pavimentação":
            self.assunto = "pavimentacao"
        elif self.root.ids.assunto.text == "Calçadas guias e Postes":
            self.assunto = "calcadasguias"
        elif self.root.ids.assunto.text == "Ciclovias, Faixas e outros":
            self.assunto = "cicliovia"
        elif self.root.ids.assunto.text == "Semáforos, sinalização e outros.":
            self.assunto = "semaforos"
        else:
            self.assunto = "iluminacao"

        self.localizacao = "POINT(" + self.gps_location + ")"
        self.params = json.dumps({"assunto": self.assunto, "localizacao": self.localizacao})
        self.headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30'}
        self.req = UrlRequest('http://aaa.aaa.com:9000/api/add/', req_body=self.params, req_headers=self.headers, on_success=self.postSucess, on_error=self.postFail)

    def postSucess(self, req, result):
        text = Label(text="Enviado com sucesso!".format())
        pop_up = Popup(title="Sucesso", content=text, size_hint=(.7, .7))
        pop_up.open()

    def postFail(self, req, result):
        text = Label(text="Erro de conexão, verifique sua internet!".format())
        pop_up = Popup(title="Erro de conexão", content=text, size_hint=(.7, .7))
        pop_up.open()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GpsTest().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

i really hate coding answers here, follow this [working code](https://pastebin.com/s7NdRHka)
i just added some variables in the app class and that of the on_location function and changed the values in the Mapview to that of the variables created in the app class. hope it works